# How to query file in hdfs which has xml as one column

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

Context: 
  I have data in a table in mysql with xml as one column.
For Ex: Table application has 3 fields. 
`id(integer) , details(xml) , address(text)` 
(In real case i have 10-12 fields here).
Now we want to query the whole table with all the fields in mysql table using pig.

Transferred the data from mysql into hdfs using sqoop with

```
record delimiter '\u0005' and column delimiter as "`" to /x.xml.
```

Then Load the data from x.xml into the Pig using

```
app = LOAD '/x.xml' USING PigStorage('\u0005') AS (id:int , details:chararray , address:chararray);
```

What is the best way to query such data.

Solution that i could currently think about.

1. Use a custom loader and extend Loadfunc to read the data.
2. If there is some way to load a particular column using xmlpathloader and rest loading normally. Please suggest if this can be done.
   As all the examples i have seen using xpath are using XML loader while loading the file.

For Ex:

```
A =  LOAD 'xmls/hadoop_books.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('BOOK') as (x:chararray);
```

3. Is it good to use pig for querying such kind of data, please suggest if there are any other alternative technologies, that does it effectively.

The size of data present is around 500 GB.

FYI i am new to hadoop ecosytem and i might be missing something trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load a specific column:

- Some other StackOverflow answers suggesting preprocessing the data with awk (generate a new input contains only the xml part.)
- A nicer work-a-round to generate the specific data with an extra FOREACH from the xml column, like:

  B = FOREACH app GENERATE details;

and store it to be able to load with an XML loader.
Check the [StreamingXMLLoader](http://blog.mortardata.com/post/61678005593/xml-pig-loader)
(You can also check Apache Drill it may support this case out of the box)

Or use UDF for the XML processing and in pig you just hand over the related xml field.